# Что написать на asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

Изучил следующие темы по [asp.net](http://asp.net):

- Серверные элементы управления
- Веб-формы Управление состоянием
- Приложение [asp.net](http://asp.net)
- Linq to entilies

По БД изучил нормальные формы и связи, базовые элементы языка t-sql.
Подскажите, что можно написать для закрепления знаний на практике.

Answer (score 1):

я например делаю сайт, что-то вроде [qiq.ws](http://qiq.ws), где можно скачивать фильмы, игры, софт и т.п. Т.е. там и регистрация с авторизацией, и профили пользователей, группы(модератор, администратор, пользователь), привилегии, рейтинги публикаций, их  оформление (bb-коды, скриншоты, обложка, описание и т.п.), редактирование. Пишу специально ради практики, потому что при написании изучаю взаимодействие с базой данных, всякие там куки, сессии, проверку на валидацию введенных данных, хеширование, защиту от xss. щас уже половину всего сделал, полностью вник в эту систему MVC. когда это будет готово примусь за разработку чего-нибудь посложнее, например интернет-магазина. Советую пойти по тому же пути

Answer (score 0):

Моё первое веб приложение было интернет-магазин. В одной из книг по [ASP.NET](http://ASP.NET) MVC реализовали, в качестве примера, SportStore. Можете написать простой сайт-магазин часов. Реализуйте фишек и функционала по максимуму с регистрацией, корзиной и оплатой по кредитной , либо другой карте. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Я, для закрепления практики, писал форум не очень большой сложности, но с полностью реалистичными возможностями. Это было интересно. Форум наподобие [gotdotnet.ru](http://gotdotnet.ru).

Кстати советую изучить [asp.net](http://asp.net) mvc и на нем писать, но это уже ваше дело.

Answer (score 0):

Очень сложно начинать с написания интернет магазина, т.к. если что то делать - то делать надо сразу качественно. Что касается интернет-магазина - то там должна быть система авторизации (я писал сам, хотя есть в меру гибкий, но не для меня - asp.net identify), далее привязка к платёжным системам-посредникам, таким как Робокасса. Далее идёт такой момент как "логика приложения". Приведу пример:
" Надо разработать страницу добавления и редактирования товара". Самым простым способом решения данной задачи будет создание двух почти идентичных Представлений и двух методов действий к ним. Вот надо постараться уместить это все в один метод и в одно представление.

Научитесь пользоваться таким инструментом как Entity Framework.

Создание движок интернет-каталога, который позже переделайте в интернет-магазин.

Если будут вопросы - обращайтесь, расскажу подробнее.